# How to combine multiple results while joining tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query which returns names of categories and its subcategories.

```
$subcategories = Subcategory::select('subcategories.name as subcatname', 'categories.name as catname')
                ->join('categories', 'subcategories.idCategory', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->get();
```

And now I get results like:

```
'Music' => 'Jazz',
'Music' => 'Rock',
'Music' => 'Pop',
'Movie' => 'Action'
```

How can I group it to have something like this:

```
'Music' => array('Jazz', 'Rock','Pop'),
'Movies' => array('Action')
```

Is it possible without making to much looping iterations and checking which subcategory belongs to which category?

Comment: Use a `group by` and `group_concat`.

Comment: Consider to use Eloquent relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel `collection`

First you need to group by `groupBy` method, then `map` each group and merge every child array.

```
$result = collect($subcategories)
        ->groupBy('catname')
        ->map(function ($item) {
            return array_merge($item->toArray());
        })->all();
```